# Problem to cast text from Windows-1252 to iso-8859-1

Tags: c#

I have a simple text encoded to windows-1252, and I must to cast this text to the iso-8859-1, however one part of the text isn't casting, this part `ï¿½` should be cast to `í`.

The text:

```
Cï¿½vel
```

Code to cast:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string broken = "Cï¿½vel XPTO";
    byte[] encoded = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(broken);
    string corrected = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(encoded);

    Console.WriteLine(corrected);
}
```

Any idea how to solve this? I've tried many things without success.

Obs.: I'd not like to replace this piece of text with `replace`

Comment: YOu don't cast text and both the codepages you mentioned are the same Latin 1. I suspect you tried to read a UTF8 file using the wrong codepage. Single-byte codepages use a *single* byte per character, not 2 or in this case, 3.

Comment: It is a garbage-in garbage-out problem.  "ï¿½" is the utf8 encoding for U+FFFD, the substitution character.   Commonly used by a text decoder to indicate that it encountered byte(s) that it could not translate to a character.  So the text was already corrupted before you got to it.

Comment: Strings in .NET (and Windows) are UTF16 - no if or but. SO itself proves this - it's an ASP.NET application. It wouldn't be possible to write `í` much less `í` and `αυτό εδώ`, characters from two completely different codepages otherwise. The problem is in how the string was stored and the actual code - how was it loaded, from where, and why was there any attempt to change its encoding?

Comment: The question's code can only *garble* the text, not "decode" anything. There's no encoding involved. Luckily, in this case it does nothing - [the two codepages are identical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) `This character encoding is a superset of ISO 8859-1 in terms of printable characters, but differs from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range.` and ` by HTML5 standards should be considered the same encoding`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm downloading this text from a website using HttpClient , I've tried to specify the encoding at the moment when I was downloading the text, without successes as well

Comment: @RenatoLeite that's what *caused* the problem - using the *wrong* encoding while retrieving the text. Again, you yourself, in your very own question, just proved there's no encoding problem. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to see any of those characters. HttpClient has no problem and almost *all* web sites use UTF8

Comment: @RenatoLeite what code did you use? Which site? If you simply used `HttpClient.GetStringAsync()` you'd get back a string that doesn't need any kind of encoding. `HttpClient` itself would convert the returned bytes into text using the HTTP response's header settings

Comment: @RenatoLeite if I use [this URL](https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/diarios/documentos/785196368/andamento-do-processo-n-1047570-9220198260100-apelacao-civel-27-11-2019-do-tjsp?ref=feed) with HttpClient.GetStringAsync()` I get back back a Brazilian page without encoding issues and the text `Apelação Cível`